# How to keep a while loop going?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am working on a program that is supposed to keep asking the user for input, sort of like a menu until they choose the option to quit. Depending on what they choose, some sort of operation will be done depending on the choice. Right now I am just trying to test that the menu will keep being printed to the user, but it exits automatically once i run the program once. This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str;
  unsigned int hex;
  int decimal;


  while(str != 'Q'){
    printf("Choose an Option (C, M, Q, S, V): ");
    scanf("%c", &str);

    if(str == 'C'){
      printf("C working.");
      break;
    }
    else if(str == 'M'){
      printf("M working.");
      break;

    }
    else if(str == 'S'){
      printf("S working.");
      break;

    }
    else if (str == 'V'){
      printf("V working.");
      break;

    }




  }
    return 0;
}
```

Q is the option that would quit the program immediately if selected, but the other ones are not.

An example output I have gotten:

```
Choose an Option (C, M, Q, S, V): M
M working. (base)
```

Comment: I thought ```break``` just exited the innermost loop, which in this case would be the if loop that i was inside of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you want to `break` on `'Q'` *only*:

```
int main()
{
  char str = null;
  unsigned int hex;
  int decimal;

  while(1 == 1) { /* infinite loop until user breaks with a help of Q */
    printf("Choose an Option (C, M, Q, S, V): ");
    scanf("%c", &str);

    if (str == 'Q') /* break on Q only */
      break; 

    /* All the other cases: perform the operation and ask again */
    if(str == 'C'){
      printf("C working.");
    }
    else if(str == 'M'){
      printf("M working.");
    }
    else if(str == 'S'){
      printf("S working.");
    }
    else if (str == 'V'){
      printf("V working.");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok I see now. I didn't think about it like that. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The break exits from the while loop. The `if` statement is not a looping structure so the `break` is for the nearest loop which is the while.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the menu to keep printing to the user just remove the break statement in each of the (if,else if) blocks. because the **break** and **continue** statements affects the nearest repetition statement to them which is the *while loop*  in your code.

[image: how break statement works]

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `str`.

```
int main()
{
  char str = 0;
  unsigned int hex = 0;
  int decimal = 0;

...
```

Comment: I had already tried that and it was still causing the same issue. Also, I read online somewhere that C automatically initialized all variables that weren't initialized to 0.

Comment: @jaaytbe You need to go back and read that again. Some variables *are* initialized to 0, but only if they are **global** variables, or variables declared with the `static` keyword. Local variables (that aren't `static`) are *not* automatically initialized, they *must* be explicitly initialized in the code.

Comment: This is why I usually don't answer SO questions anymore ‍♂️